# Cannot pass array parameter (building out html with string) - Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have modified my previous code to allow for a data array to be passed to a different function. Everything is working until I add this data array.

Currently what works (old version) is only passing the this operator and an ID.

Below in my code you will see that I build out the HTML along with a table and pass the html to be appended at a later time.

You can see that I am building a table with a delete button. It all works well, except now that I am passing the data array it is telling me "Unexpected identifier"

I have tested it with passing getDeleteItems(this,ID,ID) and it works fine
but getDeleteItems(this,ID,data) does not.

Below is my code, and you can see I am passing an array (that works throughout my code and other functions (including this one already!))

I am just stuck now and can't seem to see past this, maybe some fresh eyes can help!
Thanks!

```
function mouseOverTable(ID,parent,data)
{
    // ID is in the first column (0)
    // Type is in the second column (1)
    // Title is in the third column (2)
    // popup_ItemClicked()                      
    var family = findFamily(ID,parent,data)
    var sHTML = "";
    sHTML +=    "<table class="+"table table-hover id='relationshipTable'"+">";
    sHTML +=     "<thead>";
    sHTML +=     "<tr>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"Select Item"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"ID"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"Content Name"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"Type"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"Status"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "<th>"+"Date"+"</th>";
    sHTML +=     "</tr>";
    sHTML +=     "</thead>";
    sHTML +=     "<tbody>";
    //displays if it's a article.. blog ... etc..
    for(var i = 0; i<family.length;i++)
    {

        sHTML +=     "<tr id='relationshipRow"+family[i].ID+"'>";
        sHTML +=     "<td><input type = 'checkbox' value = '"+family[i].ID+"'></input></td>";
        sHTML +=     "<td>"+family[i].ID+"</td>";
        sHTML +=     "<td>"+family[i].Title+"</td>";
        //shows the date that the contentitem was created
        sHTML +=     "<td>" + family[i].Type +"</td>";  
        sHTML +=     "<td>" + family[i].Status +"</td>";
        sHTML +=     "<td>" + (family[i].Date) +"</td>";    
        sHTML +=     "</tr>";
    }   

    sHTML +=    "</tbody>";
    sHTML +=    "</table>";
    //console.log(data)
    sHTML += "<input type = 'Button' id ='DeleteItems' value = 'Delete Selected' onclick='javascript: getDeleteItems(this,";
    sHTML += ID;
    sHTML += ",";
    sHTML += data;
    sHTML += ");'></input>";

    return sHTML; 

}
```

I just looked at console and the element tabs in chrome: it looks like for some reason it is parsing the object as such

onclick="javascript: getDeleteItems(this,791,[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],.... and this goes on...

Comment: From what I have see, there is no error. Probably the error is in other function. Unexpected identifier always throws when you access to a value that doesnt exist or some bad concatenation of strings.

Also consider use [ES6 Template Strings](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/01/ES6-Template-Strings), [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) or another framework for templating. Your actual way is very ugly and hard to give maintenance.

Comment: Will give it a read, I have only been doing this for a few months so any tips are helpful :)

Comment: I just did some console.log prints and found that data is good within the code I posted (as figured.) However, I also added logs in the getDeleteItem function and it doesn't get to the point where it prints anything.

Comment: I also double checked my params in                                               
 `code` function getDeleteItems(THIS,ID,data)
 {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out this puzzle. I had the following functions 1) that called mouseover, the mouseover function, then the delete function. Before I was creating a delete button in mouseover(and I still am). However I made mouseover return 2 items now, one that returns the html for the table and the other that returns a tableid. I also removed the findfamily function in mouseover and moved it up to where it was being called from, then passed that as the data.

```
functionThatCalledMouseOver(ID,parent,data){
    // below have variables defining row family =findparent etc...
    row.child(mouseOverTable(ID,parent,findParent)[0]).show();
    //now create onclick even passing fullData
    $('#'+DeleteItems).on('click',function(){
        getDeleteItems(this,ID,data);
    });
}
```

My ultimate goal was the following: I had some sharepoint list items I was deleting from a table. Usually when I create charts tables etc, I will do a call and store all data locally in an array. The array is what created the table I was making. So in theory after the table data is deleted from sharepoint, it is still in my local array.

The problem with this was that when I removed the elements (visually showing they were deleted), it I hid the children of the parent in the main table I created, then clicked to show it again, it would show the deleted items since it was not server information and just a local array.

For future people reading this, I tried my original method with turning the object into a JSON string, then using the escape function. So... escape(JSON.stringify(data)).. this got passed to the delete function. This does work for appearances only. Once decoded on the getDeleteItems function it is separate data from the original data I was trying to delete. So in my case this wouldn't work.

however, moving everything to the function that originally called the mouseover was the way to go. It allowed me to get to the object I needed to remove items from.

Comment: Creating an array return on mouseover was not necessary, but I did it because I think I may need it later..

Answer (score 0):

Your error in the onclick="javascript: getDeleteItems
the third parameter expected to be an array you missed {} for the array objects.
So you must call getDeleteItems function like this
onclick="javascript: getDeleteItems(this,791,**{**[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]**}**)"

Comment: It definitely cleaned up the onclick event, but unfortunately am still getting  "Unexpected identifier"  html on page looks more like this javascript: getDeleteItems(this,791,[object Object]);

Answer (score 0):

As @Fatehi mentioned, the following lines are giving the error

```
    sHTML += "<input type = 'Button' id ='DeleteItems' value = 'Delete Selected' onclick='javascript: getDeleteItems(this,";
sHTML += ID;
sHTML += ",";
sHTML += data;
sHTML += ");'></input>";
```

I believe that adding the curly braces wont fix your issue since that `data` variable is a parameter of the function and his value it's not global and the scope when you send it to the DOM is for global variables. You should better use [data attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp) for each value and then you could access them like this:

```
<input data-test="test" onclick="console.log(this.attributes['data-test'].value)">
```

Comment: That makes more sense. I have a few ways that I think I might do this. The first way was to pass a string to the delete function then turn it back into an object. The second way I was thinking is to return a value and then continue with my data manipulation from there. If I did this, would encodeURI and decode be what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I am not going to access since attributes in the value, I am passing my whole data array so I can delete some of the items in that array.